# do you have to restart spring mvc every time?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, thymeleaf

finally after few brain meltdowns I got my spring mvc + thymeleaf working,

but every time I change something I need to restart the whole spring application?

I even tried to add spring.thymeleaf.cache=false in application.properties, I saw some people suggested it but.. nothing. it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to make changes on the back end or in the front end (thymeleaf)?

Comment: front end / index.html, well its working but I still need to Remake project instead of reloading.. it only takes like 1 second but I wish intellij would just auto remake whenever it detects a  change in my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you probably use one jar/war that you deploy. The solution could be to have a modularized project. Also if you are using IntelliJ you can check what is Hot Swap. It enables to update files while you are working on theme without necessity to rebuild the whole project on every change.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use spring boot and spring loaded by importing the spring-boot-devtools package into your pom.

Its documented under Hot Swapping in the spring boot manual and is really effective

Comment: I imported   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency> but still after refresh I don't see changes

Comment: What sort of changes are you doing - it might not work when adding a method(as is common on hotswapping frameworks), but thymeleaf changes should be ok? Have you checked the spring boot documentation as this has a section on configuration

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to do "remake" which is much faster then reloading and now it works.. but I feel I just replaced one problem with another, is there a way to Auto-Remake each time there is a change?

Comment: Theres another project - spring-loaded which might be worth a look. Spring are pushing devtools at the moment though - but ive had good results with spring loaded

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, spring-boot-devtools is an nice option but what I currently use on Intellij Idea is the JRebel plugin (https://my.jrebel.com/) and spring-boot-devtools so Thymeleaf templates get updated but with the restart option deactivated

```
spring:
  profiles: development
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false
  thymeleaf:
    mode: HTML
    cache: false
```

Comment: The plugin does not cost money, you just need to register the account. If you log on my.jrebel.com and link your social network to it, it's free.